# Sticky Nav & Resposive Nav Codes are breaking each other

Tags: javascript, function, responsive, sticky

I have a `navbar` that I want to be sticky and responsive but they break each other the sticky seems to stop the `onclick="myFunction()"` with the responsive

http://kenbeckhusen.com/

Please help!!

**Code:**

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

<script>
  window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
  
  var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
  var sticky = header.offsetTop;
  
  function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      header.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
      header.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: I am just looking at the page (Firefox) and do not see a bigger problem. except that the sticky class is added too late, so when you click "the artist", the class gets removed. perhaps you could define `var sticky = header.offsetTop-50; //or even -100` to correct that. If it's not that issue, please be a bit more precise

Comment: when you scale down your browser to mobile the menu icon click isnt working.

Also thank you,those will link to pages, the #'s are just placeholders :)

Comment: You use two times the same function name: myFunction, once for the "add responsive" and onc for the "add sticky" this gets things mixed up... change one functions name (and obviously the references to it) and everything should work

Answer (score 0):

You have two functions called myFunction.
As long as you're not in responsive mode, only one "myFunction" is used, so there's no error.
But as soon as you enter into responsive, you suddenly have two "myFunction" and everything is messed up.

Get used to use proper function names, as e.g. stickyFunction and responsiveFunction. Your problems should disappear miraculously.

```
<script>
function responsiveFunction() { //edit the call to this method Too.
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

<script>
  window.onscroll = function() {stickyFunction()};

  var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
  var sticky = header.offsetTop;

  function stickyFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      header.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
      header.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }
  </script>
```